# DBRichText "Cambria Math" auto spacing problem

Tags: delphi, richtext

I wanted to show some mathematical expressions "Cambria Math" in a DBRichText, but seems like the text is auto spacing on the top and bottom.

[image]

The (less than or equal) symbol is a "Cambria Math", it seems like auto spacing for no reason, no matter what I adjust its still the same. 
Anyone can explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

The most of Math Fonts is High Fonts. A lot of text editors works with them incorrectly, because they to get a line height in other way. More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/high-fonts-and-math-fonts